# 64byte returned value ASM

Tags: c, ассемблер

Имеется  код на С, который вызывает процедуру на ассемблере:

```
extern  double convert(char str[]);
```

Я хочу вернуть результат в ASM через `EDX:EAX`.

Вопрос. В этих регистрах уже имеется число, мне так его и оставить? Или загрузить его в `ST(0)` как одно целое?

```
int main()
{
    double result;
    char str[] = "1234567890123";
    result = convert(str);
    printf("convert(\"%s\") = %lf\n", str, result);
} // main

convert("1234567890123") = 1234567890123.000000;
```

Comment: IMHO в x86-64 сишная функция (по крайней мере в gcc) double func(...) возвращает результат в xmm0, и в нем же передается первый из double аргументов в printf.

А вообще gcc -S делает ассемблерный код.

Comment: если честно то я не очень поняла Ваш ответ..т.к. я в этом деле полтора месяца всего..

Comment: @balona, пишете маленькие программки на Си. 

Запускаете gcc -S tst.c и изучаете ассемблерный файл tst.s

Если хотите, можете его отредактировать и оттранслировать, например, тем же gcc 

    gcc tst.s

создаст ./a.out

Comment: А можно просто зайти [сюда](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) и введите Ваш с++ код и посмотрите на ассемблерный вывод.